# The Sidebar Icon image name in OSX

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-yosemite

Is this icon included as part of the Cocoa API? What is the icon name?

[image: Sidebar icon that is shown for applications such as photos and safari]

I read the HIG but could not find a reference - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/OSXHIGuidelines/SystemProvided.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000957-CH92-SW1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's undocumented. The image's name is `NSImageNameSidebarTemplate`. (`NSSidebarTemplate` in IB, though it's only visible at runtime).

I don't know though if this is off-limits and whether it will get you rejected.

Comment: Interesting tidbit: in the sample code to WWDC 2015 Sessions 221 (Improving the Full Screen Window Experience) 'Exhibition: An Adaptive OS X App' they use this image in IB. You can see a preview of it in the nib file but when you look up the image name it says 'Unknown image'. Maybe they are using a special Xcode version where you can choose it from the list of available images.

Answer (score 1):

Can't see anything that would match in the constants specified in
[NSImage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSImage/imageNamed:)  - i.e. it's not any of the images listed in [Image Template Constants](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Image_Template_Constants), [View Type Template Images](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/View_Type_Template_Images), etc. -
so I doubt it's generally available to apps..

Comment: Do you think this might be a bug? Its used so often within Apples own applications I'm surprised it's not available ?