# ToolbarItem icon set after the loss

Tags: xcode, macos, macros

my English level is limited, it may be difficult to read, please understand.
I use the NSSidebarTemplate icon in the ToolbarItem control of the project. But every time you open the Xcode, will be lost, there is no way to use NSSidebarTemplate. The missing results are shown in the picture. Open the project will have a pop-up box prompts, probably meaning

> The document "Main.storyboard" had an internal inconsistency that was
>   found and repaired.

I have no way to use this NSSidebarTemplate, but most of the other icons do not have such a problem, such as NSActionTemplate is normal

[image: Re open the project in Xcode, there are the following problems]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It comes from a template project from Apple. The image name is NSSidebarTemplate. You can see it by digging into the storyboard or xib xml:

```
<buttonCell key="cell" type="roundTextured" bezelStyle="texturedRounded" image="NSSidebarTemplate" imagePosition="overlaps" alignment="center" lineBreakMode="truncatingTail" state="on" borderStyle="border" imageScaling="proportionallyDown" inset="2" id="zzz-zzz-zzz">
```

There might have been a change in Xcode that made the image name displayed as 'Unknown' at some point, though internally it's still there.

This is also discussed here: [The Sidebar Icon image name in OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32943220/the-sidebar-icon-image-name-in-osx)